# Swift Combine create a custom Subject

Tags: swift, combine

I would like to have one `Subject` (similar to `CurrentValueSubject`) I can publish into, but that validates the value I'm sending. For example, I would like to validate that the input is forced between a range of values, like 1 and 10. If higher than the max, pass the maximum, if lower then the min, pass the minimum.

Please don't tell me to filter the result on the subscribing code because that's what I'm trying to avoid. That duplication.

Pseudo code would be:

```swift
let intSubject = ValidatedValueSubject<Int>(value: 5, min: 1, max: 10)

intSubject.sink { value in  print(value) }

intSubject.send(-10)
intSubject.send(5)
intSubject.send(15)
```

I would like this to produce:

```
5
1
5
10
```

Obviously with `CurrentValueSubject` I can't achieve that effect. 
I tried to create my own custom Subject but I can't seem to make it work.

Something tells me I should look at my problem differently because I guess this is too easy to need a custom `Subject`.

The use case:

I have a settings class which is updated on a Settings screen, and everywhere else, when the value change I want the screens to react accordingly. The `ValidatedValueSubject` lives inside this Settings object.

The Settings need to expose the `Subject` so any screens can react upon changes to the property.

My approach to the custom `Subject`is as follows:

```swift
final class QualitySubject: Subject {

    public typealias Output = Int
    public typealias Failure = Never

    public private(set) var value: Output
    private let max: Output
    private let min: Output

    init(value: Output, max: Output, min: Output) {
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self.value = value
        self.value = validated(value)
    }

    private func validated(_ value: Output) -> Int {
        return max(min, min($0, max))
    }

    var subscription: [???? QualitySubscription ?????] = []

    public func send(_ value: Output) {
        self.value = validated(value)
        subscription.subscriber.receive(value)
    }

    public func send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        print("completion")
    }

    public func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        print("send subscription")
    }


    public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, S.Failure == Failure, S.Input == Output {
        let qualitySubscription = QualitySubscription(value: value, subscriber: subscriber)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: qualitySubscription)

        // I think I should save a reference to the subscription so I could forward new values afterwards (on send method) but I can't because of generic constraints.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap a `CurrentValueSubject`:

```
class MySubject<Output, Failure: Error>: Subject {
    init(initialValue: Output, groom: @escaping (Output) -> Output) {
        self.wrapped = .init(groom(initialValue))
        self.groom = groom
    }

    func send(_ value: Output) {
        wrapped.send(groom(value))
    }

    func send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        wrapped.send(completion: completion)
    }

    func send(subscription: Subscription) {
        wrapped.send(subscription: subscription)
    }

    func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
        wrapped.subscribe(subscriber)
    }

    private let wrapped: CurrentValueSubject<Output, Failure>
    private let groom: (Output) -> Output
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let subject = MySubject<Int, Never>(initialValue: 5) { max(1, min($0, 10)) }
let ticket = subject.sink { print("value: \($0)") }
subject.send(-10)
subject.send(5)
subject.send(15)
```

Output:

```
value: 5
value: 1
value: 5
value: 10
```

Comment: Perfect! 10/10! So simple! Wrapping the underlying Subject. What I loved the most about this is that I changed the implementation of my settings model, and I didn't have to touch outside it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Appreciating the academic aspect of wrapping a subject. However from objective point of view i'm going to offer an alternative - instead of a filter i would be using **map** to force value into defined boundaries.

```
import Combine

let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(5)
subject.map { max(1, min($0, 10)) }.sink {
    print("value: \($0)")
}

subject.send(-10)
subject.send(5)
subject.send(15)
```

Same output as with the accepted answer.

```
value: 5
value: 1
value: 5
value: 10
```

Comment: Although this generates similar behaviour as the other answer, I can see at least two downsides: reusability - the code in this form can't easily be reused; and inconsistency between the current value of the subject and the value that is published downstream.